# Angular with then callback in mock jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Hi I was wondering if anyone can show me how to test a call back result in a mock test for angular and jasmine 2. We have a service that has a call that just returns some data and looks like this:

```
var getStuff = function (id) {
     return $http.get("url/" + id)
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        };
```

and in our controller, we call this service on startup :

```
angular.module('controllers').controller("myController", ['$scope',  'service', function ($scope, service) {

    var onGetStuff = function(data) {
        //do something with the result here 
    }

    $scope.getItems = function() {
        service.getStuff(1).then(onGetStuff);
    }


    $scope.getItems();
}]);
```

I am then running my test (will post code in a moment, but the call to onGetStuff is never called and I can't seem to figure out why.  Here's the test code:

```
//includes here

describe('Controller: Applicant Controller', function () {

    var controller, $q, $scope, mockService, deferred, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(module("controllers"));

beforeEach(function() {
        mockService = {
            getStuff: function (id) {
                deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve({somestuff: 1});
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };

        spyOn(mockService, 'getStuff').and.callThrough();
});

 beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, _$q_) {
        $scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $q = _$q_;

        controller = $controller('myController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            service: mockService
        });
 }));


    it("it should work", function () {
        debugger;
    });

});
```

If i step through the debugger in chrome, the mock service gets called, but the "onGetStuff" call in my controller is never called, can anyone figure out why?

thanks
Mocksy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the controller, you need to call `$rootScope.$apply()` in order to run any `then` callbacks.

Comment: thx man, completely missed that despite it being mentioned in other posts.